# Decrypt returns empty value

Tags: c#, encryption

Now I know this question has been asked before and I have tried implenting those solutions in my code but they don't seem to work as it still returns a empty value or it gives me all sorts of errors.

The decryption method

```
public string DecryptString (string encryptText) 
{  
 byte[] key {}; 
 byte[] IV = { 12, 21, 43, 17, 57, 35, 67, 27};
 string encryptKey = "aX#%710p";
 key  = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encryptKey);
 byte[] byteInput = new byte[encryptText.Length];
 DESCryptoServiceProvider provider = new DESCryptoServiceProvider(); 
 MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
 ICryptoTransform transform = provider.CreateDecryptor( key, IV);
 CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
 cs.Write( byteInput, 0, byteInput.Length);
 return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
}
```

And here is the encryption method but it works fine

```
public string EnryptString (string encryptText) 
{ 
 byte[] key {}; 
 byte[] IV = { 12, 21, 43, 17, 57, 35, 67, 27};
 string encryptKey = "aX#%710p";
 key  = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encryptKey);
 byte[] byteInput = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encryptText);
 DESCryptoServiceProvider provider = new DESCryptoServiceProvider(); 
 MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
 ICryptoTransform transform = provider.CreateEncryptor( key, IV);
 CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
 cs.Write(byteInput, 0, byteInput.Length);
 return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: The code isn't fine, you are using the `class` keyword in method definitions. This doesn't even compile. Please post *actual* code and an example that shows the problem

Comment: did you place breakpoints and investigate the data in your variables?

Comment: Also the penultimate line in each "class" is nonsense. As is the first line with the key. And there's no such class as `DESCrytoServiceProvider`.

Comment: The code `cs.Write =(...` - that's how I feel about this post... **`=(`**

Comment: Honestly I don't understand why some of you have to be so mean this is why I hate posting sometimes. I have no WiFi where I stay so I literally have to type this from from phone and as for the class and method mix up I'm not that good in c# I do what I can to make it work especially since I have an exam in a week's time to present my system.

Comment: @DaivdG DesCryptoServiceProvider is referenced by System.Security.Cryptography.

Comment: @sibysunny Please check the spelling I copied from the question.

Comment: @TheBells I'm sorry that these comments appear to be mean, but you have to see it from our point of view. Someone posts a chunk of code and says it doesn't work, but there are multiple compilation issues. Note that none of the comments were nasty, they simply pointed out the issues.

Comment: Cool and thank you for helping me fix the issues.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Encrypt

```
 public static string Encrypt(string clearText)
    {
        string EncryptionKey = "aX#%710p";
        byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(clearText);
        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
                    cs.Close();
                }
                clearText = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }
        return clearText;
    }
```

Decrypt

```
public static string Decrypt(string cipherText)
    {
        string EncryptionKey = "aX#%710p";
        byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
                    cs.Close();
                }
                cipherText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }
        return cipherText;
    }
```

Comment: This is just a dump of code with no explanation. You should be fixing the original code, not doing someone's work for them.

Comment: @DavidG i just provided an alternative solution which i know. if you know you solve the problem. Thanks

Comment: @sibysunny - I don't think your response or answer is very helpful to others. David was simply pointing out that you hadn't provided a clear explanation as to *how* you solved the problem with your code. There are varying levels of experience and knowledge on SO; and it's always best to explain your answers at a layman level, so that everyone can understand and apply your solution effectively. What (I think) David is trying to say is that SO is not a "I need this; give me code" coding service. It's designed to help people out with their issues and potentially improve their knowledge :)

Comment: @GeoffJames i don't know how to explain it. i already told that its an alternative solution for his problem. not an exact solution. if i know the working i don't have any problem to share my knowledge.

Comment: Lol I'm a she @SibySunny

Comment: @TheBells what you mean?

Comment: You said to @Geoff James "i don't know how to explain it. i already told that its an alternative solution for HIS problem.* so I'm saying I'm a she.

Comment: @GeoffJames Thanks for a much better explanation than I gave!

Comment: @sibysunny Always keep in mind that the aim of SO is to provide help to *future* readers. With a code dump specific to this question, it doesn't help anyone by the lady who posted the question.

Answer (score 0):

You have at least two issues in your *encryption* method:

- The default [mode of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) is CBC mode which requires padding to work. Padding is applied after the complete plaintext is read (or written depending on how you look at it). You either need to call [`CryptoStream#FlushFinalBlock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream.flushfinalblock(v=vs.110).aspx) before calling `ms.ToArray()` or use the `using` statement to let the language itself handle closing the stream properly as [shown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39768480/1816580) by siby sunny.
- Never store binary data in a string. Some arbitrary bytes usually don't result in a valid character encoding like UTF-8. You'd need to use a different class of encodings such as Hex or Base64 (again as shown by siby sunny).

The decryption has the same issues, but in slightly different form.

---

### Security issues

**Don't use DES nowadays.** It only provides 56 bit of security. AES would be a much better, because it's more secure with the lowest key size of 128 bit. There is also a practical limit on the maximum ciphertext size with DES. See [Security comparison of 3DES and AES](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/26179/45523).

The IV must be unpredictable (read: random) for CBC mode. Don't use a static IV, because that makes the cipher deterministic and therefore not semantically secure. An attacker who observes ciphertexts can determine when the same message prefix was sent before. The IV is not secret, so you can send it along with the ciphertext. Usually, it is simply prepended to the ciphertext and sliced off before decryption.

It is better to authenticate your ciphertexts so that attacks like a [padding oracle attack](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/18185/13022) are not possible. This can be done with authenticated modes like GCM or EAX, or with an [encrypt-then-MAC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/202/13022) scheme with a strong MAC like HMAC-SHA256.